# Help identify this connector

Tags: identification, connector, components

What is the name of this connector ?

I need to replace it but I don't know what to search for.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Edit : I added 2 photos. If it can help, the card is an SW200D1 from Advisen.

Comment: What are the dimensions of the plug and what is the pitch (center-to-center spacing of the contacts)?  Also, can you pull the plug and show us the mating face?

Comment: It could be a "molex", but that's like saying "Ford."

Comment: Also it matters if the pitch is for example 5.00mm or 5.08mm (0.2'') which isn't easy to measure.

Comment: also what shape and size are the pins.

Comment: Also how good are you at crimping terminals when you don't have the correct crimp tool?  I guess maybe you'll be able to find a pre-loaded connector and splice the wires instead.

Answer (score 1):

That is a [single wall, wire-to-board connector, 3.96 mm pitch](http://connectorbook.com/identification.html?sm=N&nm=N&bm=K&c=rectangular_conn&u=wire_to_board_conn&o=single_wall_w2b_conn&f=single_wall_w2b_conn_3p96) (my site). Manufacturers include:

- MANUF. - SERIES
- Adam tech - LHB LHC LHD + MTB (crimp)
- Molex - KK 171813 KK 171814 KK 41671 KK 41672 KK41681 KK41682 KK41791 KK41792 KK42491 KK42492 KK42891 KK42892 KK5273 KK5274 KK5277 KK8619 MV-396 + KK 2139 KK 3069 kk 5239 KK 6442 KK 41695 SPOX 43061 SPOX 5195 SPOX 5196
- Molex - KK 3190 + KK 2139 KK 3069 kk 5239 KK 6442 KK 41695 SPOX 43061 SPOX 5195 SPOX 5196
- OnShore - 8673-xx-S + 8639-xx
- TE - MTA-156 + SL-156 (1w crimp)
- Wurth - WR-WTB 645

You can buy the housing [here](https://www.digikey.com/short/hmqjd1dm) but you also may need to buy crimp contacts for it, which depend on the wire size.

Comment: Are Molex's KK and SPOX series cross-compatible?

Comment: It's complicated. They are both trademarks that are used in multiple connector families. There is no single "KK" family and there is no single "Spox" family. So, not answerable.

Comment: I ask because you list a bunch of KK part numbers and a bunch of SPOX part numbers. Are all of those connectors listed compatible?

Comment: Not exactly. They are all slightly different one way or another. For example, some have friction lock and some don't, some have two wings for polarization, some don't, some are natural Nylon, some are while polyester. I gave the person asking a list of choices.

Comment: You should perhaps make that a bit clearer, then. Say something along the lines of "It's probably one of these", rather than "manufacturers include", which suggests this is a specific very standard part that many manufacturers make compatible parts for.

Comment: How do you even know it's 3.96 mm pitch? Seems like that would be a bit difficult to distinguish from a 5 mm pitch with just pictures like that.

Comment: @Hearth. If you don't like it, please edit it. I need to move on.